# generate get next unique number from mysql ID

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to generate a unique extension for each user (this is separate from the ID but works much the same) the number should be 100 or greater and can be overwritten/custom set. Right now I am taking the next id and if it's less than 100 add 100.

So if the next id is 5 the number would be 105 but it the next id is 105 the number would just be 105. The problem is that because i'm letting the user pick their own extension if a user choose 105 before I want to make it automatically jump to the next number in this case 106. Now if there is 105, 106, and 108 I would want to jump to 107 then jump to 109.  Here is the code I'm using to generate the numbers. I think the problem is with my while loop. I'm not sure how to make it keep on checking for unique numbers.

Here is the code, I'm sure I'm overcomplicated things A LOT.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(id) 
                         FROM USERS");
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
$sql_extention = intval($row[0]);

//make sure it's at least 100
$extension = ($sql_extension < 100) ? $sql_extension+100 :  $sql_extension;

//check to see if the extention is in use
$qry = "SELECT `extention` 
          FROM users 
         WHERE extention = '$extention'";
$result2 = mysql_query($qry);

//if the extention is in use then find the next available one (this isn't currently working)
if($result2) {
  //get all results greater or equal to our extention
  $qry3 = "SELECT `id`,`extention` 
             FROM admin_users 
            WHERE extention >= '$extention'";

  $result3 = mysql_query($qry3);
  //this loop needs to be rewritten somehow to get the next number by checking if the next number exist if not return that as the extention
  $new_extention = $extention+1;

  while($extention_data = mysql_fetch_array($result3)) {
    if($new_extention != $extention_data['extention']+1) {
      $extention = $new_extention;
    }

  $new_extention++;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps getting an array of all extensions, ordered in ascending order and iterating through that until you find an unused number would work? I'd forget about the 100+n part of things; once you have more than 100 users, it'll become entirely redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came up with this, haven't tested it thoroughly but i think it should return the next available value correctly

```
SELECT (a.extention + 1) as avail 
FROM admin_users a LEFT JOIN admin_users b on ( (a.extention + 1) = b.extention )
WHERE a.extention >= 105 and b.extention is null
ORDER BY avail ASC 
LIMIT 1
```

So if this works as expected you wont need the last few lines of code at all.

Edit:
Revised the query because i realized i was approaching it from the wrong side.

Comment: That didn't work. It seems to be working backwards. It took the highest value and took away 1. For example I have an extension of 9000 and that returned 8999 I'll play around with it. It looks promising.

Comment: ah i realize whats happening, i think if you change `>=` to `>` it would work correctly, as you have already checked the existence of 105.

Comment: I think I see the problem. the user with the extention of 9000 is the only one greater than 105

Comment: try the updated query, i was approaching it from the wrong angle

Comment: @Sabeen the new query takes the highest extention and adds 1. So in my example where my extentions go from 5 then to 9000 you are getting 9001 where i would like to get 106. (thanks for all your help)

Comment: @BandonRandon are you using >= or > ? I am trying with >= and it seems to work ok.

Comment: @Sabeen I'm using `>=` I think the `105` part is the problem. What I want to do is get the next extension simi-based on the ID. So If the Id was 5 then the extension would be 105 but if 105 existed we would use 106. But I think I can make your code work.  Your code seems to get higest number greater than 105 and add 1 to it.

Comment: @BandonRandon oh yeah it doesn't take into account the 100 jump, as you seem to be already doing it in your PHP. If the inserted data is correct the 5 wouldn't be in the DB, it would already be converted to 105 before insert.

Comment: oh, is your code suppose to come after the part of my code where i'm checking to see if the extension was in the database?

Comment: yup you use it inside the `if($result2) {`

Comment: This was my initial approach, but I decided against it due to the requirement that users can choose their own extension. If you had (as a simplified example) an 8-bit extension field, and a user elected to choose 128 as their extension, the next user would be left with 129 which wouldn't work, even though there might be 127 'free' extensions (from 0-126). This is especially a problem as I imagine users will want extensions that are memorable, e.g. 9, 99, 999, 9999 etc.

Answer (score 1):

Shoddy attempt at PHP/pseudocode example as per my comment:

```
//nicer way to get the id of the user you just inserted!
$id = mysql_insert_id();

$sql = "SELECT `extension` FROM users ORDER BY `extension` ASC";
$res = mysql_query($sql);

$i=0;
while($n = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
  if($i==0){
    $i=$n['extension'];
  }
  if($i==$n['extension']){
    $i++;
  } else {
    break;
  }
}

//No existing users, start at 100
if($i==0){
  $i=100;
}
```

Then use $i as your extension.

Comment: I'd like to draw attention to `mysql_insert_id()`: the OPs approach, with `SELECT MAX(ID) FROM Table`, while simple, will give an incorrect result if another user has been created before this query runs.  E.g., Alice creates user #1, Bob creates user #2, Alice queries `MAX(ID)` and gets #2, Bob queries and gets #2, chaos ensues.

Comment: @Jon this is happening BEFORE insert. I should probably do an INSERT then UPDATE solution.

Comment: @BandonRandon: Huh, interesting.  In your case then, you should probably consider putting this process into a stored procedure with a transaction, so that the table is locked while your code settles on an ID.  Otherwise, you can still get race conditions as described above.  On a quick Google, this page describes the risks: http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/archive/2007/10/28/Conditional-INSERTUPDATE-Race-Condition.aspx.

Comment: @Jon: Yeah, I know it's something to watch out for. Right now I'm running 3 checks. 1st the query runs as in the accepted answer. 2nd some ajax checks that the extention is unique on the client side (before post). 3rd a Php check happens on the server side before insert.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so you need the next available extention higher then a given number, that is not already in the database.
So, you ideally want an array from the database that has all available extentions higher then a given key sorted ascending. Then you loop from the given number increasing by one, until it does not match. You don't mention a max number of extention. I would do it like this:

```
<?php
$rs = mysql_unbuffered_query("SELECT extention, MAX(extention) FROM admin_users WHERE extention > '$extention' ORDER BY extention ASC");
$unavailable = array();
$max = 0;
while( ($row = mysql_fetch_row($rs)) )
{
    $unavailable[] = $row[0];
    if( !$max ) $max = $row[1];
}
mysql_free_result($rs);
// Optimization for the quite common case where no more extentions are available
if( count($unavailable) > 0 )
{
    while($extention <= $max+1)
    {
        if( !in_array($extention, $unavailable) )
            break;
        $extention++;
    }
}
else
    $extention = $max+1;
// Worst case: $extention now is max + 1 and we looped through almost everything.
?>
```

Comment: Ideally I wouldn't have a max Id just allow the extentions to get bigger as the User ID increases.

Comment: @bandonrandon Then your maximum extention is always the current maximum. Editing answer.

Comment: that seems to not be returning anything.

Comment: Probably cause you use 2 different spellings of extention in your code. Either way, using a query like below seems much more preferable.